# Enlarge an image without contour having a staircase effect

Tags: photoshop, enlarging, algorithms, resize

I know it's impossible to magically "add more resolution" to a 600x600px image to turn it into a 3000x3000px image (goal: print it in around 30x30 cm). (I have done some signal digital processing math, and I know the difficulty of the problem).

But in some cases, like images with contour, drawn with MS Paint:

[image]

are there ready-to-use algorithms / software that perform better than Photoshop's resizing algorithms (I tried all of them - bicubic, etc.)?

Or even software that can reduce the staircase effect of existing pictures?

Comment: This isn't a photography question. However, the image you include looks like a good candidate for a vector format, rather than raster format. Vector formats can be enlarged without the effect you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks @osullic. The problem is that the image has been painted with MS Paint by the artist and so it's a bitmap PNG and I can have a vector file for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about graphical editing of non-photographic images. Maybe try [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: ok I'll delete myself and will repost there. Just before deleting: Any idea of software worth trying?

Comment: You could also try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) for converting raster graphics to vector graphics

Comment: this "staircase effect" is called "aliasing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution was to:

- open the PNG file with Illustrator
- Use the *Image Trace* pannel
- Select *Tracing Result with Outlines*
- Use *Trace*

Then the image is vectorized, and can be enlarged as big as we want.

[image]